# Hiding/Displaying dashboard content (tiles) based on user or group logging in using ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, grouping, dashboard

I want to know if it is possible to either hide or display the content of an Esri webapp, dashboard, or experience (tiles, widgets, data layers, filters) depending on which Portal user is accessing the application. This is through ArcGIS Enterprise Portal 10.9.

We have a dashboard that we'd like to use for several different customers, all with their own sensitive data. Can we route all of the data through the same application but constrain the data or content displayed in it based on which user is logging in?

As of now we are making separate applications for each of the customers, and giving them their own built in logins. We would like to move towards streamlining and generalizing our access.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please avoid asking questions with the words, "is this possible". On that note, what have you researched? Are you following a tutorial? What does your dashboard look like? It's difficult to help or pin point issues without pictures, code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, create separate Enterprise (Portal) Groups. For example, "Company A" and "Company B". Add users in Company A to the Company A group, likewise with Company B.

Publish data (most likely Hosted Feature Services) of Company A and share it with Group A. Create a web map with the data in it and also share it with company A. Likewise for Company B.

Then, in web appbuilder you can pass the different web map IDs via url parameters. For example, if you WAB URL is https://myorg.maps.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/123456, tack on the webmap ID that you created above like this: https://myorg.maps.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/123456?webmap=456789 and send that to Company A. Then take the same url but use the Company B web map ID and send that to company B.

Comment: I am testing this now and it does not seem to work. Are you sure on the URL pattern?